# JsBarcode is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs, jsbarcode

Using jsbarcode in my node.js web application I am unable to get rid of error: `JsBarcode is not defined`.

In my `.ejs` file I have the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jsbarcode@3.8.0/dist/JsBarcode.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
        <svg id="barcode"></svg>
        <% JsBarcode("#barcode", obj[0].num); %>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm confused as to why `JsBarcode` is undefined? I have tried making sure `jsbarcode` is installed via `npm install jsbarcode --save` and in the head of my `.ejs` file I've included the cdn `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jsbarcode@3.8.0/dist/JsBarcode.all.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, EJS is a templating engine, so packages you install via NPM would not work in this case (except you inject the content).

In your scenario you could treat it like any other HTML page. Just source the library using the `script` tag and include your code afterward

```html
// template.ejs

<svg id="barcode"></svg>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jsbarcode@3.8.0/dist/JsBarcode.all.min.js"></script>
<script>
  JsBarcode('#barcode', <%- obj[0].num %>)
</script>
```

Note that there is also a newer version of `JSBarcode` available, so I guess it's also worth updating.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jsbarcode@3.11.4/dist/JsBarcode.all.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: when I use ```<script>``` tag I am not able to access the variable ```obj[0].num``` why is that? (I am passing the variable to ```EJS``` when I render the page)

Comment: How do you pass it from your server to the template?

You can use server-side parameters in EJS like this

`<script>JSBarcode('#barcode', <%- obj[0].num %>)</script>`

Comment: To access the ```obj[0].num``` variable I used the following: ```'<%= obj[0].num %>'```